# HTML can an element be in more than one class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a ul class element like this:

```
<ul class="article-list">
    <li class="article-item">
        <header>Article #1</header>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sapiente officiis beatae, ut consequuntur. Quos minus neque eius, nemo sunt excepturi eveniet amet veritatis voluptatibus corporis ea, blanditiis porro ad!</p>
        <h3>Sample Image Title here</h3>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Placeholder Image">
        <ul>
            <li class="bold">James</li>
            <li>Lily</li>
            <li>Harry</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Magnam ex autem doloremque, tempore mollitia atque aut delectus corporis rem similique voluptates omnis reiciendis vitae impedit exercitationem unde quaerat, doloribus voluptatibus molestias et veritatis sed optio repudiandae? Provident, voluptates.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="article-item featured">
        <header>Article #2</header>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil animi ipsum, incidunt mollitia modi cum, eum ex doloremque rerum quod, maiores quisquam, enim quam unde cumque! Quam, doloremque. Voluptatum, maxime!</p>
        <p>Numquam et quae, quasi. Reiciendis nemo mollitia eveniet alias, debitis facere atque excepturi et beatae laudantium commodi optio unde amet vitae libero quas cupiditate, nam porro minus. Quisquam, odit non.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In JS, I can select one of the article-item with in feature class and toggle feature off and toggle feature on another article item:

```
var article2, articl3;
article2 = $('.featured');
article3 = article2.next();
article2.toggleClass('featured');
article3.toggleClass('featured');
```

My question is can an element in HTML be assigned to more than one class?

Comment: Yes you can have 2 or more classes in an element. You can also select it in JS like this: `$(".class1.class2")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign a HTML element to multiple classes, all you have to do is put spaces between the class names.

```
<li class="bold important">
```

The above `li` element has both the `bold` and `important` class associated with it.

EDIT: You have an example of doing this in your question (the last `li` element).

Comment: To throw some documentation behind it: [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) defines classes as "a space-separated list of the classes of the element".

Answer (score 1):

To add more than one class to an element, use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead of `toggleClass`.

```
var pElement = $( "p" );
pElement.addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
pElement.removeClass( "myClass noClass" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
```